# Cannot update attribute value in angular directive

Tags: angular, angular7

I have written attribute directive for show the error class.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: "[appErrorClass]"
})
export class ErrorClasseDirective {
  @Input('control') control: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.control)
  }
}
```

FormControl is coming from controller is working. But I cannot get form control update in custom directive. I have passed control like this.

```
<div appErrorClass [control]="userForm.get('email')">
```

But, I am not able to get updated FormControl status in directive.

Please help anyone to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In *ngOnInit*, `this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => console.log(value))`. Note that you need to unsubscribe when your control's component is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

as allready told you need to subscribe the valueChanges of the FormControl. Please dont forget to unscubscribe it when your directive is destroyed.

Here is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjz363

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. How to check dirty in onsubmit?

Comment: FormControls have a property dirty.  Since you pass the FormControl as @Input to your directive you have access to it from your component and your directive. 

` 
if(control.dirty) {
//Your Code here 
}`

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the form control using Input property binding. Use NgControl

> A base class that all control FormControl-based directives extend. It
>   binds a FormControl object to a DOM element.

Injecting NgControl you can access the formControlValue

```
import { Directive,Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAppError]'
})
export class AppErrorDirective {
  constructor(private control: NgControl) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.control.statusChanges.subscribe((e) => {
      console.log({
        valid: this.control.valid,
        dirty: this.control.dirty,
        touched: this.control.touched
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngcontrol-status-changes-d2mcsp

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. How to check dirty in onsubmit?

Comment: Yes. I need to catch it in onsubmit